# How to connection string in web.config from databases names in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown which has a list of databases. User has to select which database he has to use and then a gridview is shown.

So to display the gridview I'm giving the below connection string in code behind file.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HKI-D-SQL05\SQL2k12;Initial Catalog=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ";User Id=sa;Password=sa123"))
```

But is there anyways to list the connection string in web.congfig file? but database name has to be selected in code behind. Means server name, user id and password can be given in web config but initial catalog in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a placeholder for the database name in web.config (e.g. "`Data Source=HKI-D-SQL05\SQL2k12;Initial Catalog={{placeholder}};User Id=sa;Password=sa123`"). In code behind you get the connection string value from web.config and replace the placeholder with the selected database (using `.Replace("{{placeholder}}", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)`).

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a `switch case` in your code behind and based on that get the full connection string from the web.config?

Something like:

```
   switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue) { 
                case "FirstCatalog":
                    GetFirstConnectionString;
                    break;
                case "SecondCatalog":
                    GetSecondConnectionString;
                    break;
              ...
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurationManager to take the ConString to a list and link it to the DDL
Or you can add the DB catalogs names into 
and take them from the ConfigurationManager as well